# Getting background color from UIWebView html?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I've got a smaller UIWebView within a UIView. I want to set the UIView's background color to be the same as the webView's loaded HTML. Is this possible?

I've tried, in `webViewDidFinishLoad`, to get the color like this:

```
 NSLog(@"color: %@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.style.background"]);
```

.. but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: did you do it in - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView ?

Comment: also you can try that property document.body.style.backgroundColor

Comment: tried both things.. no joy

Comment: You should really post your HTML because this is more of a javascript question.

Comment: As others have said, you need to more specific in your question. What are you trying to load in the Webview. Is it your own HTML or will be it any website on the internet?

Comment: maybe you should use `document.body.computedStyle.backgroundColor` because your web page may not have a `style` attribute. (If the `body` css is set in a `<style>` block)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

working code in only three steps ..

1)Copy code and paste it in your project.
2)Connect ___webView outlet to UIWebView in xib file.
3)Run.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [___webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body id=\"mybody\" style=\"background-color:green;width:100px;height:100px;\"><b>Hello buddy</b></body></html>"] baseURL:nil];
    ___webView.delegate=self;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *javaScript = @"document.body.style.background";
    NSLog(@"color is %@",[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript]);
    NSLog(@"did load finish ");
}
```

//output is -----

**2013-09-03 11:56:33.187 ads[3655:11303] color is green**
**2013-09-03 11:56:33.188 ads[3655:11303] did load finish**

Answer (score 5):

In HTML resource. I use

```
body bgcolor="#FF0000"
```

In that case my code should be.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
NSLog(@"Done loading");
NSLog(@"color1: %@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:     @"document.body.bgColor"]);
}
```

Output was -

```
 2013-09-02 16:47:53.986 WebViewTest[14674:707] color1: #FF0000
```

Now, In HTML resource, I use

```
body style="background-color:#FF0000"
```

In that case my code should be.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
NSLog(@"Done loading");
    NSLog(@"color1: %@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.style.backgroundColor"]);

}
```

Output was -

```
 2013-09-02 16:55:11.531 WebViewTest[14691:707] color1: rgb(255, 0, 0)
```

As you can see, depending on how you apply bgcolor to HTML, also changes the way you access it via java script....

Hope this helps!